# How to calculate a signature with EVP_Sign functions

Tags: java, c, openssl, digital-signature

I have the following code in C, and the java code is at [openssl digest different in c compared to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608286/openssl-digest-different-in-c-compared-to-java/13610789).

```c
EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx;
unsigned char sig_buf[4096];
/* Do the signature */
int err;
unsigned int sig_len;
String testSign = "c14N string ";
EVP_SignInit(&md_ctx, EVP_sha256());
EVP_SignUpdate(&md_ctx, testSign.c_str(), testSign.size());
sig_len = sizeof(sig_buf);
err = EVP_SignFinal(&md_ctx, sig_buf, &sig_len, privKey);
if (err != 1) {
    perror("Error While generating Signature for Security Token");
    return "Null Signature";
}
return calculateBase64(sig_buf,sig_len);
```

The problem I am facing is that the signature calculated by java comes out to be different than C. This has to be done using Private key and I have SSL object from OpenSSL available.

Also just to add the following command line generates matching signature

```
echo -n "String here" | openssl dgst -dss1 -sha256 -sign client.key |openssl base64
```

Any directions in this regard would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Is this a Java question, a C question, or a C++ question? Where is your Java code?

Comment: This is a C/C++ question and the java code is the one at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608286/openssl-digest-different-in-c-compared-to-java

Comment: Is this is a double, this should be closed.

Comment: it is different the code is the same. Previously it was a digest calculation this is signature calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Replaced the following and got correct result.

```
EVP_MD_CTX_init(&md_ctx);
EVP_SignInit_ex(&md_ctx, EVP_sha256(),NULL);
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&md_ctx);
```

Reference  : 
http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/downloads/publications/hsm/hsm_node22.html

Comment: Right, the error in the code above is that you're using an uninitialized md_ctx.  The real fix here is the EVP_MD_CTX_init call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it was helpful. So if i get it right we need to initialize mdcontext and signature context both.